# How do I test if an object is a pandas datetime index?

Tags: python, datetime, indexing, pandas

If I use `type` on a `DataFrame` which I know has a datetime index, I get:

```
In [17]: type(df.index)
Out[17]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

but when I test it, I get:

```
In [18]: type(df.index) == 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'
Out[18]: False
```

I know I assumed the type of type is a string, but I really don't know what else to try, and searching has resulted in nothing.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) of the DatetimeIndex class:

```
In [11]: dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)

In [12]: dates
Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2013-01-06 00:00:00]
Length: 6, Freq: D, Timezone: None

In [13]: isinstance(dates, pd.DatetimeIndex)
Out[13]: True
```

Comment: I'd like to think I've come a long way since asking this question... (-:

Answer (score 4):

What did you import Pandas as?

If you are following the guide in the documentation and did something like:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)

type(dates[0]) 
pandas.tslib.TimestampTimestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00', tz=None)

type(dates[0]) == pandas.tslib.Timestamp
False  
# this throws NameError since you didn't import as pandas

type(dates[0]) == pd.tslib.Timestamp
True  
# this works because we imported Pandas as pd
```

Out of habit I neglected to mention as @M4rtini highlighted that you should not be using a string to compare equivalency.

Comment: The solution is to not compare against a string, but the object

Comment: Thank you.  I had 2 points of failure.  The string bit I was aware of but didn't know what else to try considering I tried to test against pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex.  testing against pd.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex which is how I imported it, did the trick.

Comment: This doesn't check whether dates is a DatetimeIndex, just that x[0] is a Timestamp... it could be a list or Series etc. with 0th item a Timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [102]: type("asd") == str
Out[102]: True

In [103]: type("asd") == "str"
Out[103]: False
```

Compare against the object, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
In : type(df.index)  
Out: pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex


In : type(df.index) == pd.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex  
Out: True
```